# What is the difference between ~ and ! operator?

Tags: java, operators

Please let me know the difference between ~ and ! operator in java.

Comment: I suggest you try some examples yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

~ is the negation operator. It negates bits from true to false or false to true. Used only with integral data types (int, short, byte, char, long).

! flips the value of a boolean. This will work on anything that will result in a logical value. So if you have foo < 5 you can do !(foo < 5) and the result will be the opposite.

Comment: `So if you have foo < 5 you can do !(foo < 5) and the result will be the opposite` i got it :D

Comment: Isn't a bool stored as a byte for memory alignment purposes though?

Comment: -1, saying that ! flips one bit is rather misleading. See tangens' answer for beter explanation.

Comment: -1 It is wrong to say ! flips a bit, the internal representation isn't specified for Java. In C, which isn't as careful as Java to distinguish integers and booleans, ! maps 0 to 1 and nonzero values to 0.

Comment: Fixed, sorry, i'm from a more of a c world.

Answer (score 12):

`~` is a [bitwise complement operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change its pattern to "11111111".

`!` is a [logical complement operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html). It inverts the value of a boolean.